# Concatenating lists using flatMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading a Java 8 book by Ricahrd Warburton and he provided the following excercise:

> try rewriting the following using method references:
>
> [...]
>
> The flatMap
>   approach to concatenate lists

I really don't understand how to apply `flatMap` here. The thing that confused me was that flat map is used to map each element of a `Stream` to another `Stream` and then concatenate them together to produce a larger `Stream` but here we have to separate `List<T>`.

```
public static <T> List<T> concat(List<T> lst1, List<T> lst2){
    //lst1.stream().flatMap() - it maps each elements 
                                //of lst1 to stream and concatenates it for each                                          
                                //element    
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the purpose of the exercise, the idea is to use [`Stream.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) to create a `Stream<List<T>>` containing the two given lists, and flat map each list with the method reference [`List::stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--). This will flatten the `Stream<List<T>>` into a `Stream<T>`. Then, you can collect all the elements into a list with [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--):

```
public static <T> List<T> concat(List<T> lst1, List<T> lst2){
    return Stream.of(lst1, lst2).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Actually, very simple. Thank you.